# R boot function - interpretation of t and t* in plot - modification of standard graphics

Tags: r, plot, graphics, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I started using the package `boot` in `R` and I am having some trouble understanding the sense of the parameters `t` and `t*` on plots.

A basic code is the following:

```
library(boot)
mydata <- c(0.461, 3.243, 8.822, 3.442) 
meanFunc <- function(mydata, i){mean(mydata[i])}
bootMean <- boot(mydata, meanFunc, 250)
plot(bootMean)
```

When using the command `plot.boot` I obtain this graphic:

[image]

What does it represent `t*`. Why the title says Histogram of t but in the x axis we have `t*`?

As an added question: How can I modify the properties of this graphic such as, for example, the color or tile or axis?

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be that t* represents the bootstrapped estimates.

Comment: I would think also the same but then why use Histogram of t as title and not Histogram of t*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the output of boot (`bootMean` in your case) one can find two types of `t`s: `t0` and `t`.

From the documentation of `?boot`:

> **t0**
>   The observed value of statistic applied to data.

This is the value of your `meanFunc` function on the original data set i.e.:

```
> mean(mydata)
[1] 3.992
```

This is called original `t*` or `t1*` in boot's output:

```
> bootMean

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = mydata, statistic = meanFunc, R = 250)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original   bias    std. error
t1*    3.992 0.165301    1.512914
```

And then you have

> **t**
>   A matrix with sum(R) rows each of which is a bootstrap replicate of the result of calling statistic

`t` here represents the matrix (vector in your case) of all the statistics produced according to your `R` argument i.e. 250 in your case.

Therefore, there is a difference between `t` and `t*` and the difference is that `t` is the matrix of all the statistics i.e. `t` here is what we would call the random variable in statistics whereas `t*` are the estimates of the `t` random variable. In your case you get 250 estimates `t*`s as determined by the `R` argument. In other words `t` is the matrix and `t*` are the elements of the matrix.

And therefore the plot makes sense as well since it is the histogram of the random variable `t` and the x-axis contains the estimates of the random variable i.e. the `t*`s.